# Логирование клика по баннеру

Tags: php, логирование

Всем доброго времени суток!

Хочу научиться логировать клики по рекламе на сайте. К сайту прикручена mysql.
На сайте есть есть html-блок, в который, если вставить прямой код на баннер, то логирование есть:

```
<div id="banner">
<img width="728" height="90" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tWVvvz4Pw5U/UcQ79QAd0YI/AAAAAAAAFqk/wy9s3rTaUkk/s1600/bb-banner-728x901.gif"/>
</div>
<div id="tech" style=""></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#banner').click(function() {
        $('#tech').load('/logging_click.php');
    });
});
```

Однако, как только заменяю прямой код баннера на код от гугл адсенс, то логирования не происходит:

```
<div id="banner">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
 data-ad-client="**************"
 data-ad-slot="***********"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>

<div id="tech" style="width:0px; height:0px;"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#banner').click(function() {
        $('#tech').load('/logging_click.php');
    });
});
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: очевидно, адсенс перехватывает клик

Comment: @Etki, т.е. логировать конкретно это событие не получится?

Comment: можно попробовать перехватывать на уровне документа. но зачем?

Comment: чистый интерес..

Answer (score 1):

Ads асинхронно подгружаются, поэтому нужен delegate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#banner img', function() {
        $('#tech').load('/logging_click.php');
    });
});
```

Но, Google adsense, насколько я видел, формирует объявление в iframe и src у iframe внешний (см. исходный код после загрузки объявления), поэтому не получится отслеживать клики по ads таким образом. Доступ к документу в iframe запрещён политикой безопасности браузера, т.к. разные домены.